# Is there a way to trigger re-run with same inputs if event happens?

Tags: cicd, concourse

Every once in awhile our workflows get a timeout.  Under normal circumstances, it will build correctly, but the nature of the pipeline is that every once in awhile it just happens.

I was curious if there is a way to trigger a "rerun with same inputs" if there is a timeout of say 30 minutes.   Right now, I was looking up and saw `CONCOURSE_DEFAULT_{GET/PUT/TASK}_TIMEOUT` as a mechanism to enforce a timeout instead of it just hanging, but i was curious if there was instead a way of it failing, to trigger the rerun.

I am newer to the cicd world.  It seems like a use case it should/would have at some point, the ability to rerun automatically